# AS3 date time removing 0 for mins

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, datetime

I currently have a piece of code that gets the time in hhmm format (eg 1254), everything i am doing is working fine other than for 10 mins every hour where the minute has a 0 before it. eg:

```
at 1:54 pm my code traces 1354  
at 3:20 pm my code traces 1520
```

the problem is

```
at 1:05 pm my code traces 135   
at 2:09 pm my code traces 149
```

I can see whats happening with the int removing the 0 but it needs to be an int to do calculations further afar, can anyone see anything obvious?

```
var td: Date = new(Date);
    trace(td);
    var formattedDate = dateToMMDDYYYY(td);
    //Hours...
    var tHrs: int = td.hours;

    var tHs: String = ""
    if (tHrs < 10) {
        tHs = "0" + String(tHrs);
    } else {
        tHs = String(tHrs);
    }
    //Minutes...

    var tMins: int = 04;
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Manually setting to 04 mins for testing

    var tMs: String = ""

    if (tMins < 10) {
        tMs = "0" + String(tMins);
    } else {
        tMs = String(tMins);
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine ( except this line : `var formattedDate = dateToMMDDYYYY(td);`, I don't know what is it for, maybe it's the function which has the next code ? ). For example here it was : 15:09, and I got 1509 ...

Comment: Also, don't forget to use the `tMs` variable and not `tMins` in your next code ...

Comment: You are sure that you use the tMs variable and not tMins for your trace,righ t? ;) Because the script looks completely fine

Answer (score 0):

If you need a 0 before an integer you should use a string. It can easily be cast into a number when you need it for calculations.
I.e.: int("01") = 1;